# how can i correctly define the href attribute using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, href

I have a link that brings the user to the Italian version of my website. I want to define the href attribute of this anchor using javascript so that it is relative to the current page. Here is the html:

```
<a href="javascript:changeLanguage()" id="lang-link"" >Italiano</a>
```

and here is the javascript:

```
function changeLanguage(){

    var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );

    var filename = pathArray[2];

    var newURL = window.location.protocol + "://" + window.location.host + "/ITALIANO/" + filename;

    document.getElementById("lang-link").href= newURL;
};
```

When I click on the link, I have to click twice to load the new page and it loads an error. My coding brings me to:


http://www.ilcataldo.com/de/http:://www.ilcataldo.com/ITALIANO/shows.html


instead of:


http://www.ilcataldo.com/ITALIANO/shows.html

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong? I am a self-taught novice!
Thanks,
Cathal

Comment: The first time you click the link, all it does is change the `href` of the link, it doesn't reload the page from that URL. You have to click it again to follow the new link.

Comment: to go to the new URL, do `document.location.href = newURL`

Comment: There's an error in your URL construction. See answer below.

Comment: Construct this link on the server side! Don't use the `javascript:` pseudo protocol.

Comment: thanks for your feedback guys. ill let you know how i get on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
var newURL = window.location.protocol + "://" + window.location.host + "/ITALIANO/" + filename;

document.getElementById("lang-link").href= newURL;
```

to this:

```
window.location = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/ITALIANO/" + filename;
```

The reason you're seeing a bad URL has to do with the construction of the URL in your code. You were inserting an extraneous `:` in the protocol prefix, which is not the proper URI format. Consequently, the browser assumed the link reference was relative to the current document.

The reason you had to click twice to reload the page is because your code was only modifying the link `href` on the first click. It was not instructing the browser to load the new page.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<a href="" onclick="changeLanguage()" id="lang-link">Italiano</a>
```

With JavaScript:

```
function changeLanguage() {
 var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
 var filename = pathArray[2];
 var newURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/ITALIANO/" + filename;
 document.location.href = newURL;
}
```